# How to use the hooks offered by Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to utilize the hooks that are commented on through the Ember Data source code, but I can't seem to implement the methods in a way where they get called.

I am currently trying to use the `keyForPolyMorphicType` which is a hook in `DS.JSONSerializer`, which is `A hook you can use in your serializer subclass to customize
    how a polymorphic association's name is converted into a key for the type.` and here is how I currently have it set up

```
var jsonSerializer = DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  keyForPolymorphicType: function(name) {
    debugger
  }
})
var serializer = jsonSerializer.create()

DS.RESTAdapter.configure('ServerDemo.Component', {
  alias: 'component'
});

ServerDemo.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  bulkCommit: false
  ,serializer: serializer
});


ServerDemo.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter:  ServerDemo.Adapter.create()
});
```

If anyone could offer guidance on how to use the hooks sprinkled throughout the source, that would be helpful

EDIT

Here are my models

```
ServerDemo.Note = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  content: DS.attr 'string'
  index: DS.attr 'number'
  noteable: DS.belongsTo 'ServerDemo.Noteable'

ServerDemo.Noteable = DS.Model.extend
  note_ids: DS.hasMany 'ServerDemo.Note'

ServerDemo.Part = ServerDemo.Noteable.extend
  rack_pos: DS.attr 'number'
  server_config_id: DS.belongsTo 'ServerDemo.ServerConfig'
  partable: DS.belongsTo 'ServerDemo.Partable', { polymorphic: true }
  note_ids: DS.hasMany 'ServerDemo.Note'
  semanticRackPos: (->
    "rack_pos_#{this.get('rack_pos')}"
  ).property('rack_pos')

ServerDemo.Partable = DS.Model.extend
  part_ids: DS.hasMany 'ServerDemo.Part'

ServerDemo.Component = ServerDemo.Partable.extend
  back_image: DS.attr 'string'
  cols: DS.attr 'number'
  rows: DS.attr 'number'
  front_image: DS.attr 'string'
  name: DS.attr 'string'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're on the right track. I would suggest to inherit from `DS.RESTSerializer` instead of `DS.JSONSerializer`.

My guess is that you are testing your code against models that don't implement correctly a polymorphic association.

Take a look at this test: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/integration/belongs_to_test.js#L119

At the top of the file, you can see how the store, adapter, serializer and models are set up.

UPDATE (after you describe your models).

One thing to pay attention to, the REST serializer camelize/decamelize attributes. You are not doing it. (`server_config_id` -> `serverConfig`)

Attributes for associations have a name that describes the model, not the attribute for the id in the json (`note_ids` -> `notes`)

You could have that working like that:

```
ServerDemo.Note = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr 'string'
  content: DS.attr 'string'
  index: DS.attr 'number'
  noteable: DS.belongsTo 'ServerDemo.Noteable', {polymorphic: true}

ServerDemo.Noteable = DS.Model.extend
  notes: DS.hasMany 'ServerDemo.Note'

ServerDemo.Part = ServerDemo.Noteable.extend
  rack_pos: DS.attr 'number'
  serverConfig: DS.belongsTo 'ServerDemo.ServerConfig'
  partable: DS.belongsTo 'ServerDemo.Partable', {polymorphic: true}
  semanticRackPos: (->
    "rack_pos_#{this.get('rack_pos')}"
  ).property('rack_pos')

ServerDemo.Partable = DS.Model.extend
  parts: DS.hasMany 'ServerDemo.Part'

ServerDemo.Component = ServerDemo.Partable.extend
  back_image: DS.attr 'string'
  cols: DS.attr 'number'
  rows: DS.attr 'number'
  front_image: DS.attr 'string'
  name: DS.attr 'string'
```

It is unclear to me if this design is what you are looking for as there is currently no need for polymorphic associations. You could reduce the number of models you define.

Comment: Cyril, thank you so much. I wasn't sure what serializer to use I have been following the example on your commit and you mention that it uses `JSONSerializer` but that probably doesn't mean to use it. I have one polymorphic assoc working it's just the second one I am adding is giving me a problem. I get an error about how my alias might need to be set, and if I set it says it has already been set :) I'll get it eventually. Thank you for your work and the time you take to respond to everyone

Comment: Feel free to post your models and how you declare the aliases, I'm happy to help.

Comment: Nice! I added the models, and my aliases are up in the original post, only have the one because when I declare the `part` alias it tells me that the `part` alias has already been declared. I should also add that everything works on the component / partable side of the code... It's only the note and noteable that can't get the type 'part' from the association. I am also using ActiveModelSerializers so the payload is standard sideloading. Thanks!